# Using Regex in python within lines of a file

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to set a variable equal to the last 6 characters in a line of an input file. Using the below code I am trying to do this but I don't know the syntax to do so, and I get a syntax error. Thanks.

```
for line in f:
    x = line[......$]
```

Here is the specific error:

```
File "bettercollapse.py", line 15
    x = line[......$]
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explain Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) as

```
for line in f:
    x = line[-6:]
```

- The negative indexing accesses the nth (here 6th) element from the end of the string.
- The column is followed by nothing, which means that it continues till the end of the string.

  That is here it takes elements from `-6` to `end` of string, the last `6` elements.

**Example**

```
>>> string = "asdfasdfqwerqwerqwer"
>>> string[-6:]
'erqwer'
```

**Note**

It do count the `\n` that may be in the file. So for safety the `for` loop can be written as

```
>>> with open('test', 'r') as input_file:
...     for line in input_file:
...             print line[-7:-1]
... 
erqwer
>>>
```

where as the older version would be

```
>>> with open('test', 'r') as input_file:
...     for line in input_file:
...             print line[-6:]
... 
rqwer
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexps aren't the right tool for this; [slicing is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/51685).

```
for line in f:
    print(line[-6:])  # print last 6 characters of line
```